# Flashing ATSAME51N19 using ATMEL-ICE

Tags: microcontroller, atmel, atmelstudio, atsam3x

I'm trying to flash ATSAME51N19 chip using Atmel-ICE, as it was having old bootloader and firmware. But getting error `Verifying Flash...Failed! address=0x0000 expected=0x80 actual=0xff`
And The fuses are

```
AC_BIAS0 = 0x01
ADC0_BIASCOMP = 0x07
ADC0_BIASREFBUF = 0x07
ADC0_BIASR2R = 0x07
ADC1_BIASCOMP = 0x07
ADC1_BIASREFBUF = 0x07
ADC1_BIASR2R = 0x07
USB_TRANSN = 0x09
USB_TRANSP = 0x19
USB_TRIM = 0x06
ROOM_TEMP_VAL_INT = 0x1D
ROOM_TEMP_VAL_DEC = 0x08
HOT_TEMP_VAL_INT = 0x69
HOT_TEMP_VAL_DEC = 0x00
ROOM_INT1V_VAL = 0x01
HOT_INT1V_VAL = 0x02
ROOM_ADC_VAL_PTAT = 0xAD8
HOT_ADC_VAL_PTAT = 0xD5D
ROOM_ADC_VAL_CTAT = 0xB71
HOT_ADC_VAL_CTAT = 0x954
BOD33_DIS = [X]
BOD33USERLEVEL = 0x1C
BOD33_ACTION = RESET
BOD33_HYST = 0x02
NVMCTRL_BOOTPROT = 64
NVMCTRL_SEESBLK = 0x01
NVMCTRL_SEEPSZ = 0x03
RAMECC_ECCDIS = [X]
WDT_ENABLE = [ ]
WDT_ALWAYSON = [ ]
WDT_PER = CYC16384
WDT_WINDOW = CYC16384
WDT_EWOFFSET = CYC16384
WDT_WEN = [ ]
NVMCTRL_REGION_LOCKS = 0xFFFFFFFF

SW0_WORD_0 = 0x1FF07FD (valid)
SW0_WORD_1 = 0x1B29 (valid)
TEMP_LOG_WORD_0 = 0x106981D (valid)
TEMP_LOG_WORD_1 = 0xD5DAD802 (valid)
TEMP_LOG_WORD_2 = 0xFF954B71 (valid)
USER_WORD_0 = 0xDE9A9239 (valid)
USER_WORD_1 = 0xAEECFFB1 (valid)
USER_WORD_2 = 0xFFFFFFFF (valid)
```

I think the issue is with the fuses  how do I reset all the fuses and do programming? How can I solve this flashing issue.

[Datasheet](https://ww1.microchip.com/downloads/en/DeviceDoc/SAM_D5x_E5x_Family_Data_Sheet_DS60001507G.pdf)

Comment: If during a verify a 0xFF is read while 0x80 is expected, maybe the programmer fails in writing the flash. This can come from many causes.

Comment: NVMCTRL_BOOTPROT = 64 as I changed this register to 0x0 as many people suggested that bootloader starts from 0x0 so it suppose to be there. now it showing new error:   Severity:  ERROR
ComponentId: 20100
StatusCode: 131103
ModuleName: TCF command: Modules:writeToMemory failed.

Failed to write segment at 0x0 to target for memorytype base